# Json object inside object via asp.net c# from sql server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, serialization

I am using [jstree](http://www.jstree.com) plugin, and I need json format that is inside object.

this is my output:

```
[{"id":"1","text":"Document Management","parent":"#","icon":"fa fa-table","selected":1}
,{"id":"2","text":"Document List","parent":"1","icon":"fa fa-list","selected":1}
,{"id":"7","text":"Hazard","parent":"#","icon":"fa fa-file-text","selected":1}]
```

**this is what I need:**

```
[{"id":"1","text":"Document Management","parent":"#","icon":"fa fa-table",state: { opened: true, selected: true }}}
,{"id":"2","text":"Document List","parent":"1","icon":"fa fa-list",state: { opened: true, selected: true }}}
,{"id":"7","text":"Hazard","parent":"#","icon":"fa fa-file-text",state: { opened: true, selected: true }}}]
```

and these are my c# and js codes which creates json serialising and treeview;
c#

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Menu()
{
    ClassSystemAccessPolicy classDocumentPolicy = new ClassSystemAccessPolicy();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = classDocumentPolicy.Permission_Load().Tables[0];

    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

js

```
var MenuTree = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Permission.aspx/Menu",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var menu$json = JSON.parse(data.d);
            $('#tree_menu').jstree({
                'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox", "types"],
                'core': {
                    "themes": {
                        "responsive": false
                    },
                    'data': menu$json
                }
            });
            console.log(menu$json)
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('err')
        }
    });
```

How can I serialise like `state: { selected: true }` ?

Comment: why in the world does .NET return the JSON with "d" as the random parent node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own DTO(Data Transfer Object) for this

```
public class JSTreeDTO
{
public string id{get;set;}
public string text{get;set;}
public string text{get;set;}
public string parent {get;set;}
public string icon{get;set;}
public StateDTO state{get;set;}
}

public class StateDTO
{
 public bool opened{get;set;}
 public bool selected{get;set;}
}
```

Then create it inside loop

```
List<JSTreeDTO> treeList=new List<JSTreeDTO>();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    JSTreeDTO node=new JSTreeDTO();
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        node.id=dr["id"];//etc
        node.state=new StateDTO();
        node.state.opened=true;//based on your logic           

    }
    treeList.Add(node);

   return serializer.Serialize(treeList);
}
```

Comment: It returns `"state":[{"Key":"opened","Value":true},{"Key":"slected","Value":true}]}`and I removed datacolumn foreach, because it gave me an error. I use `dr["id"].toString()`

Comment: @user3436421, I changed my implementation and updated my answer

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan why in the world does .NET return the JSON with "d" as the random parent node? Is it possible to change that?

Comment: @mmcrae there is a possible attack when you just return array of objects in Json output. Please read out Phil Haack article http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/

Comment: But from what I can tell, the "d" parent is not solving that/changing that. If I return an object that has say `{"Tag":"cars", "Rank":"2"}` -- no array present -- .NET still changes it to `{"d":{"Tags":"cars",...}}` (along with adding other random crud...)